# RSpec - Feature teste falhando porque elementos não estão renderizados na execução do teste

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec

tô com um feature teste falhando porque no momento que ele roda alguns elementos HTML (`<li data-podcast>`) ainda não foram renderizados.

Alguém sabe como consigo fixar isso?

```
RSpec.describe 'Podcasts List', type: :feature do
  scenario 'A user visits the root page and views a podcasts list' do
    visit '/'

    within '[data-podcasts]' do
      expect(page).to have_selector 'li[data-podcast]', minimum: 3
    end
  end
end
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: São renderizados via JS?

Comment: @LuizCarvalho não, uma variável de instância é populada com todos os arquivos do db (`@podcasts = Podcast.all`) e então faço um each listando todos eles (`@podcasts.all.each do ..`).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

Quando rodamos nossos testes, a base de dados de teste é acessada, e não a de desenvolvimento. A solução foi instanciar todos os objetos que eram usados na feature test:

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:podcast, 3)
```